# Is it possible to submit your own admin forms in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I'm wondering if is possible and how could do it, to create my own page in Wordpress, after that I want to submit the form, do something with the info and then save it. It sounds simple, but for so much I find no results.

I saw that I can use `do_settings_sections` to create my custom form easily, but it auto-saves, what I want is to refer to a function and later show another screen.

Far at the moment, I am close, calling a function from y form with this:

```
function edit_university() {
        echo " *test* ";
    }
add_action( 'admin_post_edit_university', 'edit_university' );
```

I submit the form and I see the echo test, but I get out of the Wordpress admin page. It's just a simple page with echo test; how can I resend it later to another page?

Comment: Can you make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have now and explain the workflow a bit better?

Comment: yes, Basically, I want to submit a form, from X php file I did reference before, and capture the info, I want that form to be custom, made by my own, and I dont know how to reference the action URL to my plugin (all this is in the admin side)without getting out of the wordpress admin page (as another admin page)